# how can i print 0 right triangle in c?

Tags: c

Pattern :

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int value = 6;
 for(int i = 1; i < value+1; i++);
 {
  for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++);
   printf("0");
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

And also the 1st row consists of 1   0's, the 2nd row 2   0's, and so on, until the Nth row, which consists of N zeroes. like below pattern.

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000
```

Note: I have to give positive integer N and print N rows.

MY ERRORS:

```
Program: In function 'main':
Program:7:21: error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function)
Program:7:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: remove the `;` at the end of the `for(....` lines

Comment: @disha , Please accept answers which helped you!

Answer (score 3):

You have a `;` at the end of both of your `for` statements, this closes the for loop immediately, which means the `i` variable is then out of scope and unavailable for use.

Comment: yea correct. thanks. but if i give 2 input it showing 6 lines of zeros. why?

Comment: i mean in above program i gave int value = 6 then i got this output                   0
00
000
0000
00000
000000    then i tried with 2 again its showing same                0
00
000
0000
00000
000000    i need 1st row consists of 1 0's, the 2nd row 2 0's, and so on, until the Nth row, which consists of N zeroes. like above pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In C don't declare, variables inside `( )`.

```
int i;  // declare globally
//  do your stuff
for(i = 1; i < value+1; i++)
```

If you put `;` colon after loop statement, the loop blocks there itself till the condition fails. it will execute the next line. So remove the `;` after `for` loops.

Try this-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int value,i,j;
        printf("Enter the number of rows\n");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        printf("-----------------\n");
        for(i = 1; i < value+1; i++)
        {
                for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                printf("0");
                printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: yea correct. thanks. but if i give 2 input it showing 6 lines of zeros. why?

Comment: @dishajaiswal  2 input means what?

Comment: Declaring variables in `for` is valid in C99.

Comment: in above program i gave int value = 6 then i got this output                   0
00
000
0000
00000
000000    then i tried with 2 again its showing same                0
00
000
0000
00000
000000    i need 1st row consists of 1 0's, the 2nd row 2 0's, and so on, until the Nth row, which consists of N zeroes. like above pattern.

Comment: @dishajaiswal: Perhaps you've forgotten to save your changed file or to recompile?

Comment: your not getting my point. i need pattern. example: suppose if i give 2 input i need output: 1st row one 0 then 2nd row two 0's. if i give 6 input i need output : 1st row one 0 2nd row two 0's ... 6th row six 0's.. like i mention in my question (pattern)

Comment: This is exactly the output I get when I compile Sathish's code (before his edit), once with `value = 6` once with `value = 2`. Yes, I don't get your problem.

Comment: @dishajaiswal if your problem solved validate the answer that solved your problem by clicking the tick mark!

Answer (score 0):

First remove the semicolon & remember for control structure you can not put semicolon at the end of it, so remove semicolon ,

Seceondly, if you are still getting error put your int i and j outside of for loop,

Comment: yea correct. thanks. but if i give 2 input it showing 6 lines of zeros. why?